# data passing in navigation based application

Tags: iphone, ios4

i am working on a navigation based application
in the rootviewcontroller i hav a few UITextFields. There is a button on rootviewController, on clicking that button i am changing the view using pushviewcontroller. I want to use values entered in these UItextFields in mapview ie my 2nd view.

PLZ suggest me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could pass all the information to your second controller before pushing to navigation stack.

**See the pseudo code for your reference :**

**First:**

```
MyMapController* myController = [MyMapController alloc] initWithValues:Value1,value2,value3,......valuen];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];

[myController release];
myController = nil;
```

**Second:**

```
MyMapController* myController = [MyMapController alloc] init];

myController.value1 = value1;
myController.value2 = value2;
myController.value3 = value3;
............

myController.value7 = value7;
myController.value8 = value8;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];

[myController release];
myController = nil;
```

There could be more approach for sending the data,

Comment: but how am i supposed to do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing assign the values to the second controller.
Say you have to send value of textfield1. Now

secondController.textfield1 = textfield1;

Then do your pushing of controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSDictionary` object to store the values from the first controller. Say you are using two text fields – textField1 and textField2.

```
- (void)loadSecondController {
    NSDictionary *values = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:textField1.text, @"textField1", textField2.text, @"textField2", nil];

    // Assuming you are using IB files
    SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.values = values; // Declare a NSDictionary property 'values' in SecondViewController
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

Now in `SecondViewController`, you can access them as

```
...
textField1Value = [values objectForKey:@"textField1"];
textField2Value = [values objectForKey:@"textField2"];
...
```